# CSS color flip dark to light

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a css file that has hex color values for my python project using pyqt5. The problem is that it is only for dark mode, but i would like the same thing but for light mode. Is there any way i can flip all the colors to have a light mode css stylesheet?

Comment: Flip all the colors automatically? You could do it with CSS with `filter: invert(100%);` but it will look bad. You should go through and define a dark and light version for each color (use CSS variables to handle swapping themes).

Comment: you may use CSS [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) ?

Comment: thank you both of your solutions they both worked

Comment: Note that just flipping color values may not be suitable for some entities: some contrast may work fine for a color combination, but that may not be equally valid for their opposites, possibly making some text difficult to read. This may also be problematic for colors used for pseudo 3D effects: for instance, inverting the colors used for buttons may completely change their perceived appearance, with a "raised" button looking like it's pressed. You may consider converting that file to a "flipped" one and carefully test it, eventually changing colors that don't work well in that mode.